# DataMember.Name ignored by WCF JSON serialization?

Tags: json, wcf

I have a WCF service to which I am adding new endpoints that use idiomatic HTTP+JSON. I bumped into the DateTime formatting issue, and tried to fix it like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class PingResponse
{
    [IgnoreDataMember] public DateTime SystemDateTimeLocal;
    [IgnoreDataMember] public DateTime SystemDateTimeUTC;
    [DataMember] public string Version;

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = nameof(SystemDateTimeLocal)), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string SystemDateTimeLocalFormatted
    {
        get => SystemDateTimeLocal.ToString(Constants.DateTimeFormat);
        set => SystemDateTimeLocal = DateTime.ParseExact(value, Constants.DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = nameof(SystemDateTimeUTC)), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string SystemDateTimeUTCFormatted
    {
        get => SystemDateTimeUTC.ToString(Constants.DateTimeFormat);
        set => SystemDateTimeUTC = DateTime.ParseExact(value, Constants.DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

But, the resulting object is serialized with `SystemDateTimeLocalFormatted` and `SystemDateTimeUTCFormatted` properties, ignoring the `Name` on the `DataMember` attributes. Is there a way to achieve what I want that doesn't involve swapping out the serialization stack? :-P

---

Update: I just copied this type into a test app and explicitly used `DataContractJsonSerializer` and it did not ignore the `Name` field -- so I am forced to conclude that the original project is archieving its JSON serialization with a different serializer. I haven't yet looked into identifying which one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause. It's a weird one. I found a dummy `DataContractAttribute.cs` in our project. This was silently taking the place of the real `DataContractAttribute`, so that `DataContractJsonSerializer` didn't detect the type having a data contract. Removing the `DataContractAttribute.cs` from the project so that the source code instead uses the real `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute` has resolved the problem.